# Encrypt text using Caesar's Cipher

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption

I was writing this C program which takes in a command line argument , and then encrypts a text later entered by the user.

We enter a number through command line which is used in encryption. For eg , if we eter a number 1 from command line and then the user wants to encrypt say "aaaa" , the encrypted text will be "bbbb" , just that each has shifted one character. I made my output but there is no text printed back . What is my mistake?

Here is my code

```
int main(int argc , string argv[])
    {
       if(argc != 2)
         {
            return -1;
         }
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Enter the text to be encrypted : ");
    string text = get_string();
    int length = strlen(text);
    for(int i=0 ; i<length ; i++)
       {
           int p = text[i];
           int c = (p + k) % 26; 
           printf("%c",c);
        }
   }
```

Comment: is `string` a typedef for `char *`, or what?

Comment: Can you please add the code to the `get_string()` function to your question

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Yes. It's the anti-pattern fostered [here](https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_string)

Comment: Ceasers? I think it's spelled "scissors". You just run over your text with them several times, as thoroughly as you can.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yeah. Im using cs50.h from harvard classes , so we can use string there.

Comment: @sudoman get_string() is a function inside cs50.h which gets a string. Its as simple as that.

Comment: I don't believe they're teaching this at harvard :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala im taking their course from edx.org . They have this course called cs50 which teaches computer science fundamentals.

Comment: @SriramR - The astonishment is not at Harvard teaching CS, but at the fact they give you the `string` typedef. That typedef is all kinds of bad.

Comment: Yeah this is only the second video. They cover pointers and char * in the fourth lecture. I cant use char * until I reach the problems from the fourth lecture.

Comment: If you cannot use `char *` how can you use strlen? That function accepts a character pointer. This is just asinine on their part.

Comment: Its not that I cant use. Its that they  havent covered it in this current topic and so I shouldnt probably use it. string is essentially char *. Si strlen() works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code here:

```
int c = (p + k) % 26; 
printf("%c",c);
```

will most probably not print anything worthwhile, because the resulting values will be in the 0..25 range, that in ASCII are different control characters. What you want to do is to check if the character is ASCII lowercase or ASCII uppercase, and only then do the rotate, and ensure that the result is also in the same range:

```
unsigned int c = text[i];
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
    c = ((c - 'A') + k) % 26 + 'A';
}
else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
    c = ((c - 'a') + k) % 26 + 'a';
}
printf("%c", c);
```

If the value is between `'A'` and `'Z'`, we subtract the code for `'A'` so that these map from `0` to `25` (note that we're assuming alphabetical consecutive ordering of character codes from `A` to `Z` here - this works on ASCII, but doesn't work on an IBM mainframe with EBCDIC, so consider yourself be warned!), then do the modulo math there, then add the code for `'A'` again to get into the original range.

We do the same in `else if` for lowercase letters.

Comment: your code didnt work bro. For a key of 1 and text aaaa , the output was {{{{

Comment: @StoryTeller yeah, fixed.